# ipad: app cannot be installed at this time

Tags: ios, cordova, certificate, phonegap-build

I am completely new to iOS app development process and I have issues with the installation on the actual device.

Yesterday or the day before I made the first certificate and a provisioning profile which only contains the UUID of our development iPhone. I uploaded the certificate along with the provisioning profile to PhoneGap build and initiated the first build of the app's iOS version (the app has been built/tested on WP8/Android a hundred times before). Then I installed it on the iPhone and it worked.

Now I wanted to add one iPad to the build cycle. I logged into apple developer, added the iPad to the devices section, added it to the existing provisioning profile, downloaded that provisioning profile to my computer, overwriting the old one, uploaded the certificate and the provisioning profile to phonegap build (they only allow to upload a "new" certificate, not to edit the provisioning profile of the old one, but I had the copy of the certificate still on my computer), unlocked it, selected that the application build process should work with the "new" certificate/provisioning profile, and rebuilt the iOS application.

Then I took the iPad, logged into phonegap build and downloaded the app for installation.

The error I then got was "app cannot be installed at this time". I understand that this error message is caused mostly by certificate issues, at least in developer environment.

How can I now find the exact reason for this?

Comment: The process sounds about right and yes, the _cannot be installed at this time_ usually indicates problem with certificates.

Comment: @Alexander if you have resolved the issue please share the solution. That might help others.

Comment: @kumar The problem is solved, but I don't know why/how. Maybe the issue was caused by the phonegap build hard disks running full last friday, which led to a service disruption only hours after I had this issue. I doubt it, but when I built again on monday, everything was fine, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue. Please double check that your provisioning profile conatins the **UDID** of the device. You can use **iPhone Configuration Utility** application on windows to check the error logs.